# JBoss Fuse - Relative paths for bundles

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have a camel project, where I use a java bean reference.
Inside this .java I'm reading a file which path is "`src/main/resources/basic.xml`"

I build the osgi-bundle with apache felix and I write the instruction:

```
<Include-Resource>src/main/resources</Include-Resource>
```

The bundle builds fine, and I also test with another maven plugin (mvn camel:run)
and everything works fine =)

Then I deploy it on my osgi container (Karaf) adding all dependencies for this OSGI, but it fails
cause is not finding basic.xml

```
FileNotFound /home/user/jboss-fuse-xx/instances/testCOntainer/src/main/resources/basic.xml
```

If I change the path on my .java like "basic.xml" the result is:

```
FileNotFound /home/user/jboss-fuse-xx/instances/testCOntainer/basic.xml
```

So the relative path is the container root path, where I deploy this bundle.

The easy way to resolve this, is to put the basic.xml in this path, I know :P, but ¿is there another way?

Is there an apache felix instruction that fix this??? so the bundle can resolve this path, no matter where is deployed

I've worked with the Import-package instruction before and works fine, but only when I 'call' this resource on a camel route, not in a java class.

Thanks for all the answers !!

Comment: try getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("basic.xml"); inside your ".java" to access your file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the basic.xml file is found, the problem is that this xml calls another file (dtd) an once again is searching for this at the container root path, is something similar used in java but for xml ??

Comment: If it is spring/blueprints context, you could try 'classpath:resource/some_file.xml' instead of 'resource/some_file.xml'. Not really sure if it would work for dtd.

Comment: I'm working with two proyects, a sender  and a receiver of bytes (...) I just edit one of them and skip the other. The problem is solved. Thank you white !!